# Htaccess error 404 subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have this in my htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?options=error404
```

It works fine when I try to open `http://localhost/nopage`

But if I call: `http://localhost/nopage/anysubdirectory` the error page not show well with no style or nothing.

You can see and example at https://www.redjuvensar.org/nopage

And the problem at https://www.redjuvensar.org/nopage/otherdir

Answer (score 0):

Due to the change in the directory, your resources are throwing a 404 (open the console). Make your `href` and `src` of your files absolute, not relative.